# How can I align an image to the right but have it go under another image that is already aligned there?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to get an image aligned to the right side of my container div but I already have an image there. Simply using a margin property gets the image where I need it to be but that does not help because there is an image scroller to the left of it and it pushes that down also.

This is currently how it looks; the "payment gateways" image is where i need it to be with the use of float & margin-top properties. The margin-top somehow applied itself to the banner also making this move down - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/smK37.jpg

-----[ 2 ]--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ 1 ][ 3 ]

Image 1 is the scroller and image 3 is the one in question. Need image 1 to stay next to 2 and still have 3 stay underneath.

```html
<div class="container">   
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-inner">
        <a href="http://www.website.co.uk/delivery-info"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/allordersshippedfree-280-140.jpg') ?>" alt="" id="icon-cart1" align="right" /></a>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ma_banner') ?> <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/Payments.png') ?>" alt="" id="icon-cart1" align="right"/>
```

Comment: Please post your code. And as for an image, you can post a link to it and someone with enough rep and embed it.

Comment: I think for most of us it's not really clear what you mean by 'under another image'. Do you mean they are on top of eachother and on the same location, but overlapping? Or do you really mean physically have one image below another (so one is positioned beneath the other, on a new line so to say)?

Comment: Apologies, I mean so that one is positioned below the other(like on a new line).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the style `z-index`.

[What is z-index?](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: It's not a matter of layers though, I mean the physical position on screen. Sorry if there is some mis-understanding, it's hard to show what I mean with no image.

Answer (score 0):

z-index is a part of what you are looking for.

To place the images on the right with overlap you need to use a combination of position: absolute, right: distance, and z-index ...

```
<head>
  <style>
    .right {
      float: right;
    }
    .over {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      z-index: 200;
    }
    .under {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      z-index: 100;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img class="right over" src="http://bob.fornal.org/images/stories/Main/bob.jpg" />
  <img class="right under" src="http://bob.fornal.org/images/stories/a_certified.jpg" />
</body>
```

Comment: This does work however I am building for a responsive website; I am trying to avoid using absolute positions.

Comment: absolute means: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.  So, basically, if the element wrapping these images is non-static, then it uses that as the relative starting point.  This can still be used effectively with responsive (this is not fixed positioning).

Answer (score 0):

Given your update, look at clear: both, or left, or right as a means to keep floated right but underneath the previous image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just tried this and the image still sits next to the previous image.